# Redirect one URL to another, keeping page the same? (Apache2)

Tags: apache, redirect, apache2

Let's say I have two domains: mydomain.org and mydomain.net

We are currently using the .org domain but would like to migrate to .net

Is there a way I can do this in apache, such that if a user tries to visit mysite.org/somefolder/somepage that it will automatically redirect to the corresponding link on the .net site?  (so mysite.net/somefolder/somepage)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- First make sure you can control apache config and enable `mod_proxy` via `httpd.conf`

Then enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mydomain.net%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L,NE]
```

Comment: Another Condition and Rule can be added, so the www. requests are also redirected properly!

Comment: @M-z: Regex in my RewriteCond `mydomain\.org$` will match `www.mydomain.org` also.